# Adding a field to specific line in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is there a way to add a field to a record on a specific line?

This may not be that important due to the nature of NOSQL in general but I want things to be in order if possible.

I know there is the `$addfield` parameter in the aggregation but this will add it to the final line in the JSON record.

Any ideas?

Example:

```
{
    A: "name" 
    B: "surname" 
    D: "Phone-number"
}
```

And I want to add something along the lines of this:

```
   {
        A: "name" 
        B: "surname" 
        C: "address"
        D: "Phone-number"
    }
```

Comment: A field is like a key-value into the object, so you can't ensure the order. To add a field you can use `$set` too.

Comment: @J.F. I'll try it out. I'm still learning and in the early stages of aggregation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can post examples using `$set` and `$addToFiles` if you want. Also, using `$set` is only an update, you don't need aggregation.

Comment: Also check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IzMISHyhnHz). It seems key fields are sorted alphabetically.